# Replace all ocurrences by string with special characters in java

Tags: java, string, replace, pattern-matching, match

I have the next string:

```
String var = "Hello NAME_USER, welcome to NAME_USER, your name is NAME_USER";
```

I want to replace all occurrences of `NAME_USER`, the problem is when `NAME_USER` has special characters (ex: `!"#$%&/()=)(/&%`), a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` is thrown.

The complete code:

```
String var = "Hello NAME_USER, welcome to NAME_USER, your name is NAME_USER";
var = var.replaceAll("NAME_USER","!#$%&/()=)(/&%");
```

The exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal group reference
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Matcher.java:857)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.replaceAll(Matcher.java:955)
    at java.lang.String.replaceAll(String.java:2210)
    at com.vupc.colegios.infraestructura.utilitarios.UtilitarioPlantilla.reemplazarTexto(UtilitarioPlantilla.java:119)
```

Note: `NAME_USER` can be replace by any `String`.

Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use [String#replace()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) instead of [String#replaceAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

or [String#format()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) with numerated arguments:

```
String var = String.format("Hello %1$s, welcome to %1$s, your name is %1$s", username);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use String.replace(CharSequence,CharSequence).